# I am using python 3.9.4 the latest version of python but am running the code below and am getting invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is the code

```
spam = 0
while spam < 5:
    print('hello')
    spam = spam + 1
```

I have try to run the code and try to debug it but to no avail.
I have search on the internet for solutions for this type of invalid
syntax

Comment: This code works perfectly fine. You'll need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67094837/edit) and add more information about the error you're receiving.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: The code is perfect and will compile without any errors

Comment: but this is giving me a an invalid syntax I don't know what is causing it with python 3.9.4